# Function definition not returning objects

Tags: python

In my code, only addToDict returns object myDict. The rest of the function definitions seem to not return anything, even though i return. What may be cause of that? How can i fix it? Please help...

In the txt there are only randomly distributed characters.

```
from pathlib import Path
from string import ascii_letters

def readFile():
    filename = str(input('Enter filename: '))
    assert len(filename) > 0, "Filename shouldn't be empty!"
    assert not filename.isspace(), "Filename shouldn't containt any whitespace character"
    if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename += '.txt'
    assert Path(filename).exists(), "File was not found"
    return filename

def countChars(text, character):
    charCounter = 0
    for char in text:
        if char == character:
            charCounter += 1
    return charCounter


def percChars(character):
    isPerc = round(100 * countChars(content, character) / len(content), 2)
    return isPerc

def addToDict(dictionary):
    for letter in ascii_letters:
        dictionary[letter] = list([countChars(content, letter), percChars(letter)])
    return dictionary

def filterDictionary(dictionary):
    dictionary = {key: value for (key, value) in dictionary.items() if value[0] > 0}
    return dictionary

def sortDictionary(dictionary):
    dictionary = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0])}
    return dictionary

def displayDictionary(dictionary):
    for item in dictionary:
        print("'{0}' is present in the text: ".format(item), end='')
        print(dictionary[item][0], 'times,', str(dictionary[item][1]) + '%')

with open(readFile()) as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
    myDict = {}
    addToDict(myDict)
    filterDictionary(myDict)
    sortDictionary(myDict)
    displayDictionary(myDict)
```

Comment: Please give an example input that returns "nothing"

Comment: "seem to not return anything" You are going to have to be more specific. Note, most of your functions *do* return things, but you never do anything with the value that is returned.... so I'm not sure how you discern if they return something or not

Comment: Note, your `sortDictionary` doesn't return anything, you probably want `return dictionary` too.

Comment: Are you collecting the returns at all? I mean, `filterDictionary` returns yes, but you're not handling the return when doing the function call? Or are you expecting to modify the reference (pass by reference instead of pass by value)?

Comment: As others have said, the problem here is probably that you're ignoring the return values.

Comment: @Torxed note, python uses *neither* of those evaluation strategies. It is almost always better to not even bring them up, unless you are coming from a language that *does* use them (e.g. C++, Fortran, C)

Comment: But why can I use the myDict returned by addToDict in display, and I cannot use the ones returned by filter and sort?

Comment: @FilipSzczybura because `addToDict` *mutates* the dictionary you pass in, which happens to be the same dict you pass to `display`, the others do not, they merely create new dictionaries and return them, but are discarded immediately, since no reference to the exists after the function terminates. Generally, it is considered bad practice to mutate your inputs.

Comment: So by using the filter and sorted, I create new objects, while in addToDict I change the myDict object. Do I understand correctly ? And why is it bad to mutate my inputs? How to change my coding style to be considered as a good code?

Answer (score 1):

Last 4 lines should be:

```py
    myDict = addToDict(myDict)
    myDict = filterDictionary(myDict)
    myDict = sortDictionary(myDict)
    displayDictionary(myDict)
```